# Airflow Trigger Rule Wait for Parent Tasks to finish

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

For my DAG I have a main task(task_1) and then I have 4 additional tasks that follow and need to be executed in sequential order due to system constraints.

Tasks 2,3,4, and 5 need to be executed in sequential order but are dependent on task_1 being successful but are not dependent on other tasks being successful.

So if task_1 is success, then task_2 should kick off, if task_2 fails, task_3 would then kick off because task_1 finished successfully and task_2 has completed although it failed.

I tried using `one_sucess` for tasks 2,3,4, and 5 but as soon as task_1 completes, all other tasks kick off instead of running in sequential order.

Is there a way to wait for all parent tasks to complete?

```
 task_1>> task_2>> task_3>> task_4>> task_5>>email
 task_1>> task_3
 task_1>> task_4
 task_1>> task_5
```

Comment: Use a different trigger rule: `all_done` ([see documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/concepts.html?highlight=trigger%20rule#trigger-rules)) for instance, should work

Comment: In the example, I tried to articulate that Task_1 is the main task and needs to be a success in order for any of the other tasks to execute.  If I set the trigger rule to `all_done` for tasks 3, 4, and 5, they will execute regardless if task_1 is successful, however, they should not execute if task_1 fails.

Comment: Hmmm ok, I see. Then maybe Task 2 could have `all_sucess`, and Task 3, 4 and 5 have `all_done`? I'm actually not sure if the `upstream_failed` would propagate to task 3,4,5 in the case task 1 fails

Comment: It would be great if I could set task 2 to `all_success` and then tasks 3,4, and 5 set to `one_success`&`all_done`, so they would have both trigger rules.

Comment: Task 3, 4 and 5 should use `none_failed_min_one_success`. Task 2 should have default trigger rule i.e. `all_success`.

Comment: `none_failed_min_one_success` didnt work and my understanding is that none of the parent tasks can fail.  In the example, I have assigned task_2 `all_success` and task_3 `none_failed_min_one_success`.  Task_3 is dependent on task_1 being a success and task_2 completing.  Task_3 needs to run regardless if task_2 is success or fail. When task_3 is set to `none_failed_min_one_success` , when task_2 fails, task_3 wont execute.